# Окно в Tkinter зависает при использовании thread.join()

Tags: python, многопоточность, tkinter

У меня есть окно с кнопками старт и стоп. При нажатии "стоп" программка зависает. Мне хотелось,чтобы  func() заработала после завершения потока.

```
def btn_start():
   thread.start()


def btn_stop():
   event.set()
   thread.join()
   func()
```

Comment: Используйте `thread.is_alive()` https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-thread/.

Answer (score 1):

Просто не используйте `.join()`. Использование этого метода блокирует основной поток (на то время, пока поток не завершится), и не дает выполняться циклу обработки событий tkinter.

Функцию можно вызвать прямо из выполняемого потока, когда внутренний цикл завершится, пример:

```
import threading
import time
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

event = threading.Event()


def loop():
    i = 0
    while not event.is_set():
        label.config(text=i)
        time.sleep(1.0)
        i += 1
    
    func()


def func():
    label.config(text="Stopped")


def btn_start():
    global thread
    thread = threading.Thread(target=loop, daemon=True)
    thread.start()


def btn_stop():
    event.set()


root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=btn_start).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Stop", command=btn_stop).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Если нужно выполнять именно из основного потока, то делаете периодическую проверку, жив ли поток (через метод `.is_alive()`, как предложил [@Сергей Кох](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/487882)), и если нет - то выполнить функцию, если еще жив, то проверить чуть позже:

```
def btn_stop():
    event.set()
    check_thread_finished()


def check_thread_finished():
    if thread.is_alive():
        root.after(100, check_thread_finished)  # выполнить эту же функцию через 100 мс
        return
    
    func()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот так:

```
import threading

event = threading.Event()

def func():
   print("Hello, world!") # просто пример

def btn_start():
   global thread
   thread = 
   threading.Thread(target=func)
   thread.start()

def btn_stop():
   event.set()
   thread.join()
   func() # лишняя строка, функция будет вызвана автоматически после завершения потока
```

Comment: Вы пробовали ваше решение в tkinter?